# ruby solr search within object rather than in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, mongoid

I'm using sunspot_solr gem with my rails app and below is my method for searching users

```
users = customers_object.search do
    fulltext params[:query]
end.results
```

but the search does not happen in my customers_object objects but it searches within the whole model, I could not find any resources on how to achieve this, is this possible ? if yes can anyone guide me how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found it, I was also using cancan gem and I was supossed to do `User.accessible_by(current_ability)` rather than `current_users_customers_object`, may help someone

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such syntax

```
 current_user.customers.search
```

Guess it just works, because the `search` method is defined on the Customer class.

You should index all user_ids within Customer Index, then pass the proper `with` scope.

```
class Customer

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  searchable do
    integer :user_ids, multiple: true
    ....
  end

end


Customer.search do
  with :user_ids, current_user.id
  fulltext param[:query]  
end
```

Comment: I think u didn't understand my question, what I mean is      `User.search do` is working fine but how do I search on a array of user objects ?

Comment: Only by specifying a proper filter on User.search such as `with :user_id` or whatever the field is called. Searching on an array directly is not supported. If you post you exact model relationship definition i can write the exakt sunspot query

Comment: I think you are still getting it all wrong, a user will create customers and the user is only allowed to search on his customers not on customers created by someone else so I can't do `User.search do` so I need `customers_object.search do` but sadly it isn't working

Comment: Because it's not possible :))). Don't u think, that u are getting something wrong then? An ActiveRecord query like `current_user.customers.where(customers: {name: 'john'})` produces a sql like  `SELECT * FROM users JOIN customers ON .. WHERE user.id = 4711 AND customer.name == 'john'`. It's not searching on an array of customers or the like, it's just passing the id of the current_user (4711) as a WHERE scope. So for the solr query you have to do the same thing

Comment: Don't u think that I know that I'm stuck and that's the reason why I posted the question in the first place and I have asked in my question "if it is possible"

Comment: In generall it's possible to search only on current_users customers. But not by the syntax you tried. Just add your model relationship defenetions to the post and i will write a proper sunspot query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65133/discussion-between-subash-and-dre-hh).